# Compress PDF document/Reduce size of PDF using unity script in OnBase for Workflow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pdf, itext

Trying to compress PDF using unity script in a 'OnBase workflow system work'. But, giving me an error Exception:

```
iText.Commons.Exceptions.UnknownProductException: Product pdfOptimizer is unknown. Probably you have to register it.
   at iText.Commons.Actions.EventManager.OnEvent(IEvent event)
   at iText.Pdfoptimizer.PdfOptimizer.Optimize(PdfReader reader, Stream outputStream)
   at iText.Pdfoptimizer.PdfOptimizer.Optimize(Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream)
   at CompressPDF.CompressPDF.compressPDF() in :line 131
```

expected results should be the document which is in the workflow after the script gets executed, the PDF document should get compressed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.